# When using Firebase, GoogleSignIn is marked as internal and should not be accessed from apps

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I'm trying to retrieve a list of the signed-in user's contact emails in my Android app. Starting with the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in), the following line:

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

results in the Android Studio error "GoogleSignIn is marked as internal and should not be accessed from apps".

The project compiles, but when I try to sign in, `logcat` outputs:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12210000 but found 11947470
```

My `app/gradle.build` contains:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and when I comment Firebase out:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.0'
}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't get the error and successfully sign in.

I want to integrate Firestorm into my app, do I need to redesign the sign-in process? If so, how?

To reproduce, here's my `MainActivity`. With Firebase compiled, the `Log.w` call outputs `signInResult:failed code=12500`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1000;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

and my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.XXX.MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/google_sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'm attempting to implement the new google play services implementation and am getting this error warning too. I expect many will have this issue as developers convert to the new 'simpler' implementation.

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, the entire authentication process using **[Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** and **[Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6)**. You can take a look.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo but from what I can tell you're using version `11.8.0` for both play services and firebase. The errors I'm talking about don't show up when I revert to `11.8.0` but I want a forward-facing solution.

Comment: Yes, that's right. 11.8.0 for both play services and Firebase will work for sure. What do you mean through "forward-facing solution."? Would you like me to write this as an answer?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm new to Android development but if using `GoogleSignIn` is incorrect in version `12.0.0` I want to know what I should be doing instead, without reverting to previous versions; and if this is a bad approach, I'd like to know why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

> **Known Issues with version 12.0.0**
>
> ...
>
> - An annotation causes spurious lint errors claiming GoogleSignIn and    CredentialsClient are internal-only. These can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix until Google updates their documentation for the proper usage of `GoogleSignIn` after adding the [`@Hide`](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-undocumented-hidden-apis-android-p/) annotation, revert back to version `11.8.0` for both [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_18_2017_-_version_1180) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20171218).

Comment: This compiles, but if this isn't proper use of `GoogleSignIn` with Firebase I'd like to start using it properly. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `requestProfile()` method call when creating the `GoogleSignInOptions` object like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile() //Added
            .build();

 mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'`